# In python with pandas, how to add a column with other columns compare

Tags: python, pandas

now I have a dataframe like:

```
A,B
1,2
4,3
5,5
```

and I want add a column C, if A>B then C=1, if A < B then C=-1, if A=B then C=0

Now I use for loop to do that, but I do not think that is a right way. What is the right way please?

Comment: It looks like you are describing the sign operation: `np.sign(df['A'] - df['B'])`

Comment: If want post answer, I can remove it from my answer ;)

Comment: @ayhan Should've posted an answer buddy

Comment: @ayhan Thank you, it is so nice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
m1 = df.A > df.B
m2 = df.A < df.B

df['C'] = np.select([m1,m2], [1,-1], default=0)
```

But nicer is `ayhan` solution from [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46925084/in-python-with-pandas-how-to-add-a-column-with-other-columns-compare/46925111#comment80797002_46925084):

```
df['C'] = np.sign(df['A'] - df['B'])
```

---

```
print (df)
   A  B  C
0  1  2 -1
1  4  3  1
2  5  5  0
```

Comment: Thank you. but sorry, my question was edited by me just now. I try your code like this: df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] > df['B'], 1,-1), but can not set C=0 when A=B. could you help me again please? sorry for my mistake before editing.

Comment: I edit answer too ;) Better as multiple `np.where` is use `np.select`

Comment: But if want use `np.where` - `df['C'] = np.where(df['A'] > df['B'], 1 ,np.where(df['A'] < df['B'], -1, 0))`

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend `sub` + `clip`:

```
df['C'] = (df.A - df.B).clip(-1, 1)
df

   A  B  C
0  1  2 -1
1  4  3  1
2  5  5  0
```

If your columns are floats, add an `astype` call before clipping.

```
df['C'] = (df.A - df.B).astype(int).clip(-1, 1)
```

Comment: Thank you. I know it now. clip is right when the numbers are integers, float type has a little problem.  But I know this way from you, thank you.

Comment: @xunitc An `astype(int)` conversion would handle that easily. See edit.

Comment: @xunitc I'd wager speed wise it's pretty up there. Maybe not as fast as sign but definitely faster than select/where.

Comment: I do not know which is faster, but this is simpler than where. And yes, I use sign now. :)

Answer (score 1):

Alongside the other nice answers, a simple step by step translation in pandas would look like this:

```
In [77]: df
Out[77]: 
   A  B
0  1  2
1  4  3
2  5  5

In [78]: df['C'] = 0

In [79]: m1 = df.A < df.B

In [80]: m2 = df.A > df.B

In [81]: df.loc[m1, 'C'] = 1

In [82]: df.loc[m2, 'C'] = -1

In [83]: df
Out[83]: 
   A  B  C
0  1  2  1
1  4  3 -1
2  5  5  0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `np.where` to assign a new column `C` equal to a value of 1 if `A` is greater than `B` otherwise a a value of zero.  Then use `.loc` to check where `A` and `B` are equal, where you then assign column `C` with a value of zero.

```
df = df.assign(C=np.where(df['A'].gt(df['B']), 1, -1))
df.loc[df['A'] == df['B'], 'C'] = 0

>>> df
   A  B  C
0  1  2 -1
1  4  3  1
2  5  5  0
```